# How can I get rid of this ValueError

Tags: python, machine-learning, error-handling, tensorflow

weights and biases

```
self.weights = { "layer1":tensorflow.Variable(tensorflow.random_normal([self.state_size, self.neurons_layer_1])), "layer2":tensorflow.Variable(tensorflow.random_normal([self.neurons_layer_1, self.neurons_layer_2])), "layerOut":tensorflow.Variable(tensorflow.random_normal([self.neurons_layer_2, self.action_size])) }
self.biases = { "layer1":tensorflow.Variable(tensorflow.random_normal([self.neurons_layer_1])), "layer2":tensorflow.Variable(tensorflow.random_normal([self.neurons_layer_2])), "layerOut":tensorflow.Variable(tensorflow.random_normal([self.action_size])) }
```

model function

```
def model(self, X, weights, biases):
    layer1 = tensorflow.add(tensorflow.matmul(X, weights["layer1"]),biases["layer1"])
    layer1 = tensorflow.nn.relu(layer1)

    layer2 = tensorflow.add(tensorflow.matmul(layer1, weights["layer2"]), biases["layer2"])
    layer2 = tensorflow.nn.relu(layer2)

    layerOut = tensorflow.add(tensorflow.matmul(layer2, weights["layerOut"]), biases["layerOut"])
    layerOut = tensorflow.nn.softmax(layerOut)

    with tensorflow.Session() as sess:
        init_op = tensorflow.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init_op)
        q_values = sess.run(layerOut)
        return q_values
```

I compute the predicted value like this. State is a list like this :

```
predicted = self.model(state, self.weights, self.biases)    # state = [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9]
```

these are my placeholder

```
X_placeholder = tensorflow.placeholder("float", [None, state_size])
Y_placeholder = tensorflow.placeholder("float", [None, action_size])
```

this is my cost function

```
cost = tensorflow.reduce_mean(tensorflow.square(right_prediction - predicted))
```

this is my optimizer

```
optimizer = tensorflow.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

then I initialize the variables above

```
init = tensorflow.global_variables_initializer()
```

and run the session

```
with tensorflow.Session() as sess:
                sess.run(init)

                for epoch in range(1):
                    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X_placeholder:X , Y_placeholder:Y})
```

Now I run this code and it throws the following error.

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not 
support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(4, 24) 
dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(24, 24) dtype=float32_ref>", 
"<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(24, 2) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 
'Variable_3:0' shape=(24,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_4:0' shape=(24,) 
dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_5:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>", 
"<tf.Variable 'Variable_6:0' shape=(4, 24) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 
'Variable_7:0' shape=(24, 24) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_8:0' 
shape=(24, 2) dtype=float32_ref>", 
"<tf.Variable 'Variable_9:0' shape=(24,) dtype=float32_ref>", 
"<tf.Variable 'Variable_10:0' shape=(24,) dtype=float32_ref>", 
"<tf.Variable 'Variable_11:0' shape=(2,) 
dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).
```

So please help me.

Thank you for your attention.

EDIT: ok here is my whole code, I don't know if this is legito post it with this link but [here](https://hastebin.com/ihuficecen.rb) it is.

Comment: You should show how `predicted` is computed

Comment: ok thanks, I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that there is no connected way from your optimizer to your parameters, in the other words the parameters (weights and biases) are unknown for the optimizer.

Since you didn't post your whole code, it seems you define your parameters and model inside a class, and use optimizer outside of it, do both of them as the same way, either define parameters, model, cost, and optimizer inside the class or define all of them outside.

Comment: thanks. I edited my post with a link to the code. It would be nice if you could explain it a bit more on my code. thank you Ali Abbasi.

Comment: your code has lots of mistakes in way of training and computing cost, they are not related to each other, I can't edit your code because you should change all of your structure, instead you can look at my code here: https://github.com/AliAbbasi/Multilabel-Image-Classification-with-Softmax/blob/master/multilabel-softmax.py and act like that. Define a class for your model, and define everything as a function inside it, include parameters function, score function, cost and optimizer function like the way I defined, feel free to again comment here if you have any question.

Comment: Ok thanks alot. I will try now to rewrite it in the same structure as you have. But I see one problem. My code is a reinforcement learning structure (at least I tried) and yours is a convolutional neural network. So do you have an example for a DQN-model ? thanks for your support :)

Comment: Your welcome, I am happy can help you, unfortunately, I have not DQN-model examples.

Comment: Ok I tried to write new code. But unfortunatly there are new problems :D. So maybe you can help me. I opened a new question right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942443/why-am-i-getting-this-valueerror thanks for your help