# Why am I getting this ValueError?

Tags: python, error-handling, tensorflow

So here is my code for a full understanding: https://hastebin.com/qigimomika.py
.

So basically I have a problem with the following lines:

a bit context:

```
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tensorflow.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.01)
    return tensorflow.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tensorflow.constant(0.01, shape=shape)
    return tensorflow.Variable(initial)

w_layer1 = weight_variable([4, 32])
b_layer1 = bias_variable([32])

input_layer = tensorflow.placeholder("float", [4])
```

the line which produces the error:

```
h_layer1 = tensorflow.add(tensorflow.matmul(input_layer, w_layer1),b_layer1)
```

When I run the whole code (which is above) it produces the following ValueError

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') 
            with input shapes: [4], [4,32].
```

Now my question: What happens and how can I avoid this ?

*Thanks for your attention*

***EDIT***: thanks to Prune and Ali Abbasi.

My solution: I changed the input_layer to:

```
input_layer = tensorflow.placeholder("float", [1, 4])
```

The problem was that my first array was tensorflow rank 1 ([4]) and my second array rank 2 ([4, 32]). So I added this line:

```
state = [state]
```

whereby state the input is:

```
output_layer.eval(feed_dict={input_layer : state})
```

state was initially [1, 2, 3, 4] (rank 1), now it is [[1, 2, 3, 4]] (rank 2).

***thanks***

***EDIT2:*** Ok I changed a lot since the last EDIT. I got lost of the changes to record them. In case you want to see my code [here](https://hastebin.com/mezukojome.py) it is. I know it's messy as fuck. For now I am just soo happy that shit is working :"D. You will not be able to understand my code it's a total mess but I just wanted to document the current state. A big ***thanks*** to ***Ali Abbasi*** :D.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: thanks for your response. I changed it a bit so I hope it is ok this way.

Comment: Close enough.  We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  For NNs, this should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are since you know `MatMul` operations is classic Matrix Multiplication operation so if we want to multiply two matrices, `M1` and `M2`, with shape `AxB` and `BxC` respectively, we should have same shapes `B` when we want to multiplication and in result:

`M1 x M2` results in a matrix `R` with shape `AxC`.

So in your case you try to multiplication two matrices with shape `4x1` and `4x32`, so it throws an error of shape problem, you should transpose the first tensor, then you have:

`1x4` MatMul `4x32` result in `1x32` matrix.

Your code here:

`h_layer1 = tensorflow.add(tensorflow.matmul(input_layer, w_layer1),b_layer1)`

Use like this:

`h_layer1 = tensorflow.add(tensorflow.matmul(tf.transpose(input_layer), w_layer1),b_layer1)`

For more detailed answer, you can print the shapes of tensors in each stage like:

`print h_layer1.get_shape()`

And see the shapes, then you can modify your shapes and inputs.

Good Luck.

Comment: Ok thanks again :D. It wasn't exactly the solution but it led me to it. I will edit my post and get the solution in there.

Comment: Glad to be useful answer :)